Suddenly Cannot Connect to Eduroam
I’ve previously been connected to Eduroam for a year but suddenly last week I disconnected and couldn’t reconnect. No obvious cause.
Wi-Fi still works at home + Eduroam still works on my other devices so its nothing to do with my account.
I have:

forgotten the network and reconnected with both what they recommend and also changing small things
deleted and redownloaded the certificate (and the IT guy I went to tried some others + other setting combinations)
fully updated everything

I used journalctl -r and the relevant things seem to be FT: Invalid key management type (128) and wlp2s0: Association request to the driver failed
There’s also a few lines saying supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning <- (wrt the same network interface)
I can probably get a screenshot later if the rest of the information is important but I’d really appreciate any help :,(
I’ve been to both IT help desks here (one’s student run)they told me to send a ticket to online IT but after a week of back and forth with them they’ve closed the ticket and told me to go back to the IT help desk. I really don’t want to do a full wipe of my laptop cause it’s such a pain to get the Wi-Fi driver back without Ethernet (wont have any till Christmas)

Basic starting point is what Ubuntu product & release you're using, you've not yet told us this detail.
